# Filter database children and return each name as String

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

I have been working on an application in the newest version of Xcode and Swift with Firebase Realtime Database (through CocoaPods), and I have a big problem. I would like to filter through each child of my Database and only return ones that have "user: cvb" in it. I have found a way to filter each result, but after this I want to see a sibling of the result as a String (I need it to be a String so that I can programmatically create a label with this name).

EX:

```
users
  cvb
    events
      // This should be read and name: "abgdeze" returned as a String not Any
      randomChildNameThatIWillNotKnow
        name: "abgdeze"
        users: "cvb"
      thisShouldBeFilteredOut
        name: "irrleveant"
        users: "irrleveant"
```

```swift
let xPos = 100
var yPos = 100

let query = userRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "users").queryEqual(toValue: filters)

query.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
  for childSnapshot in snapshot.children {
    print(childSnapshot as? String ?? "")

    let labelNum = UILabel()

    labelNum.text = childSnapshot as? String
    labelNum.textAlignment = .center
    labelNum.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    labelNum.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let width = bounds.size.width
    let split = "\(width / 7)".components(separatedBy: ".")
    let oneSeventh = Int(split[0]) ?? 0
    let oneBox = oneSeventh
    labelNum.frame = CGRect( x: xPos, y: yPos, width: oneBox, height: oneBox)

     self.view.addSubview(labelNum)
     // The Labels display nothing inside and are just blank boxes

     yPos += 100
  }
})
```

Expected: The boxes display one after another with the name element in it
What happens: The boxes are well positioned but blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which node does `userRef` in your code refer to. I believe it has to be referring to the `events` node for your query to work.

`let eventsRef = dbRef.child("users").child("cvb").child("events")`

Once you get a reference to the `events` node, your problem comes down to only extracting data from the snapshots. `snapshot.children` is an `NSEnumerator` object which you can use to iterate through all the children of the snapshot. In fact, the children are just another `DataSnapshot` objects. To extract the data from a `DataSnapshot` object, you use the property `value`, which returns `Any?`. You can then cast it to the expected type (in your case, `[String : String]`).

```
    let eventsRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child("cvb").child("events")
    let query = eventsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "users").queryEqual(toValue: "cvb")
    query.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let childSnapshot = child as! DataSnapshot
            let retrievedEvent = childSnapshot.value as! [String: String]
            let name = retrievedEvent["name"]
            let users = retrievedEvent["users"]
            // .. //
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add useref to the question but had it in my code, I just though I didn't use it in the code so I cut it out. Thanks for the answer, it's perfect and will test it out soon!